# How do I prove $\sum_{i=0}^{\log_3{n}}3^i = \frac{3n - 1}{2}$?

Tags: logarithms

I started my data structures course at university and I came across with that equation, can someone explain me how I prove it please?

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_3{n}}3^i = \frac{3n - 1}{2}$$
$$3^0+3^1+ ...+3^{\log_3 (n)} = \frac{3n-1}{2}$$
$$2(3^0+3^1+ ...+3^{\log_3 (n)}) = 3n-1$$
$$2+2\cdot3+2\cdot3^2 + ...+2\cdot3^{\log_3 (n)} = 3n-1$$
$$3+2\cdot3+2\cdot3^2 + ...+2\cdot3^{\log_3 (n)} = 3n$$
$$\frac{3+2\cdot3+2\cdot3^2 + ...+2\cdot3^{\log_3 (n)}}{3} = n$$
$$\frac{3(1+2+2\cdot3 + ...+2\cdot3^{\log_3 (n) -1})}{3} = n$$
$$1+2+2\cdot3 + ...+2\cdot3^{\log_3 (n) -1} = n$$
$$3+2\cdot3 + ...+2\cdot3^{\log_3 (n) -1} = n$$

Can I continue from here?

Comment: The sum is of $\;1'$s, or what? I mean, what are you suming?

Comment: Where is $i$ in the expression

Comment: @Joanpemo sorry, I edited it

Comment: Is $n$ assumed to be an integer power of 3, or is there some approximation going on for other values of $n$? If $n$ is indeed assumed to be an integer power of 3, then just use the finite geometric series formula and simplify.

Comment: @lan `@ArchisWelankar Edited

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula for sum of geometric (finite) series:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_3n}3^i=\frac{3^{\log_3n+1}-1}{3-1}=\frac{3n-1}2$$

In general:

$$\sum_{k=0}^M r^k=\frac{r^{M+1}-1}{r-1}$$

You can prove this formula by induction.

Comment: You want $M$ in your general formula, not $k$. Also, there is a simpler algebraic proof: $rS_M=S_M-1+r^{k+1}$, solve for $S_M$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you, Of course itmust be $\;M\;$ . Typo corrected. That algebraic formula also uses hidden induction, I believe.

Comment: Rigorously yes, you have to use induction to get $rS_M=S_M-1+r^{M+1}$, but that's just because it is a statement about all natural numbers. It is clear what is going on without having to explicitly write out the induction.

Comment: @Ian Thank you. True, I agree with you. Yet someone very strict could require induction.